# Move dashicons.min.css to Footer

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

Hey there WordPress community,

Google page speed is moaning about dashicons.min.css being on our site. However, we need it for the Mega menu.

I wanted to know if it's possible to move it to the footer.

I have tried this code already:

```
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'my_deregister_styles' );
function my_deregister_styles()    { 
   wp_deregister_style( 'dashicons' ); 
   wp_enqueue_style( 'dashicons', array(), false, true );
}
```

I have also tried a few other samples, however, nothing seems to work here.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below code :

```
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'my_deregister_styles' );
function my_deregister_styles()    { 
   wp_deregister_style( 'dashicons' ); 
}
```

Replace your css path "PATH_OF_CSS" :

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'register_wp_footer', 11 );
function register_wp_footer() { 
    wp_enqueue_style( 'dashicons', 'PATH_OF_CSS' ,array(), false, true );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was very close. I just had to remove: ",array(), false, true".

Answer (score 1):

Final working solution was:

```
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'my_deregister_styles' );
function my_deregister_styles()    { 
   wp_deregister_style( 'dashicons' ); 
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'register_wp_footer' );
function register_wp_footer() { 
    wp_enqueue_style( 'dashicons', '/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css');
}
```